# dbt - Invalid argument [Invalid Job UUID provided.] for table function. Table function argument is required to be a constant

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

i have a model like this wirh a post_hook configured like this:

```
{{ config(
        materialized = 'table',
        post_hook = "{{ log_error('db.schema.table', '_last') }}" -- both strings
) }}
```

and the macro:

```
{% macro log_error(table_to_validate, job_id) %}
{{
    config(
        materialized = 'incremental',
        unique_key = ['error', 'file', 'rejected_record'],
        incremental_strategy = 'merge',
        merge_exclude_columns = ['error', 'file', 'rejected_record']
    ) }}

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE(VALIDATE(table_to_validate, JOB_ID => 'job_id'))
{% endmacro %}
```

but when the run gets to the model above and error occurs,

```
Database Error in model model_1 (models/model_folder/model_1.sql)
21:51:19    002001 (02000): SQL compilation error:
21:51:19    Object 'TABLE_TO_VALIDATE' does not exist or not authorized.
21:51:19    compiled Code at target/run/workspace/models/model_folder/model_1.sql
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: When you use table to valide you use it not as a sting, but when you use job id (in you macro) you use it as a string constant. It feel like the latter is wrong

Comment: Hi @SimeonPilgrim, thanks for the reply. Yeah when i call the macro i pass both parameter as strings: log_error('db.schema.table', '_last') but in the validate function i was putting job_id between ''. I test that just now removing the '' but gives me the same error

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim additionally i changed the macro like this:

{% macro log_error_but_validate(tabla_validate, job_id) %}

MERGE INTO db2.schema2.LOG_ERROR log USING
(
WITH log_err AS (
    SELECT 
        ...
    FROM 
        TABLE(VALIDATE(tabla_validate, JOB_ID => job_id))
)
SELECT 
   ...
FROM
   log
) qr1
ON 
   ...
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THE INSERT (...)
VALUES (...)

Comment: Hiow you use the varablies inside the macro is different. One you just use, the other, also the one you use inside single quotes and it is the one you are getting an error message about. I do not use dbt so cannot say “it is wrong” but it sure looks wrong and is inconsistent.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim if i changed the VALIDATE function like this: TABLE(VALIDATE({{ tabla_validate }}, JOB_ID => '{{ job_id }}')) gives me another error: Invalid argument [We couldn't find a copy for this table which occurred during this session ] for table function. Table function argument is required to be a constant.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim the thing is if i run this query directly on snowflake as: TABLE(VALIDATE(db.schema.table, JOB_ID => '_last')) It WORKS!, the second parameter is for sure a string, the first one has to be taken as an object of snowflake, something like that

Answer (score 0):

ok, so lets work through what I am trying to say:

here is a table (that has never been loaded into, just inserted into)

```
select * from test.test.a1;
```

[image]

okies, lets [validate](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/validate) that ;-)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALIDATE(test.test.a1, JOB_ID => '_last'));
```

> Invalid argument [We couldn't find a copy for this table which occurred during this session ] for table function. Table function argument is required to be a constant.

this makes sense we didn't load into it! But that is your "error" when you write your BDT script correct (as far as I am concerned).

so now lets "load some files" from the tables empty stage:

```
copy into test.test.a1 from @%a1;
```

[image]

now lets validate that:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALIDATE(test.test.a1, JOB_ID => '_last'));
```

[image]

as expected..

so lets try an session variable, I expect this to fail:

```
set job_id = '_last';
SELECT * FROM TABLE(VALIDATE(test.test.a1, JOB_ID => '_last'));
```

[image]

well that is awkward, I was expecting to get an error about "not being able to handle the UUID of the job id", because I had assumed the code expected hardcoded job id's...

lets try a cross join to force the error:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    select '_last' as id
) as job_ids
,TABLE(VALIDATE(test.test.a1, JOB_ID => job_ids.id));
```

> Invalid argument [Arguments for Validate must be constant] for table function. Table function argument is required to be a constant.

ok, so now we are closer to your error, albeit the sub error is different.

I wonder if DBT is using a parameterized execute, which would make the value not be constant.

...

so one of of your other errors is about not existing, the one shown at the bottom of your example, so lets find a table that does not exist and see what that does:

```
select * from test.test.not_exists;
```

> 002003 (42S02): SQL compilation error:
>
> Object 'TEST.TEST.NOT_EXISTS' does not exist or not authorized.

so now lets validate that:

```
SELECT * from TABLE(VALIDATE(test.test.not_exists, JOB_ID => '_last'));
```

> Object 'TEST.TEST.NOT_EXISTS' does not exist or not authorized.

if we look at the actual return JSON object we see:

[image]

so there is the error message you see at the end of your post.

So in summary, use the correct macro expansion of your table in the form you note in the comment (btw, it's better to put updates into the question that in comments)

```
 TABLE(VALIDATE({{ table_to_validate}}, JOB_ID => '{{ job_id }}'))
```

make sure your `table_to_validate` actually exists, AND has been loaded into, and you should be golden.

### new session, same worksheet:

```
SELECT * from TABLE(VALIDATE(test.test.a1, JOB_ID => '_last'));
```

> Invalid argument [We couldn't find a copy for this table which occurred during this session ] for table function. Table function argument is required to be a constant.

[image]

So as the error states "there has been no data loaded IN THIS SESSION", which means the COPY INTO and VALIDATE need to be done on the same session chain.

Comment: Dude, thanks for the reply, i did that, i made the COPY INTO in snowflake into the table, load 20k rows and immediately run the process in DBT but again, same error, Invalid argument [We couldn't find a copy for this table which occurred during this session ] for table function. Table function argument is required to be a constant. i'm thinking maybe, like DBT is outside of snowflake, maybe doesn't have the same session as snowflake, maybe i would try to execute the manual copy directly from DBT, thanks again

Comment: The session word is the hint i believe. Do the copy into in the same sql connection to test. I was thinking about this over night. How to show. But I suspect if I ran the work validate this morning I too would get the session error instead of working.  Will test soon